# How can i Integrating the MiniMob Ads SDK in my android application?

Tags: android, mobile, sdk, ads

i want to add the MiniMob Ads in my android application. I have read the full documentation from the http://www.minimob.com/integration-guide.html for minimob sdk, but i still dont get it.

Now i have two queries:

We have to give the app url either of the android market or some other when we create new app using the MiniMob sdk. So how can we give that url like 1st upload the app without that minimob integration and get the url of the app and then again upload with the minimob integration.

And the 2nd thing is we have to just give that app id, app key and package name in the manifest and add the jar file in lib. and rest some code which i shown below in that activity where we want to show these Ads. Am i wright ??

```
    <!-- MiniMob Manifest declaration start -->
<activity android:exported="false"
                android:name="com.minimob.android.OptinActivity"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="\@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
<activity
                android:taskAffinity=""
                android:name="com.minimob.android.PushAds"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                android:theme="\@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
                <intent-filter>
                          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
                <receiver android:name="com.minimob.android.DeliveryReceiver"
                                                android:exported="false"/>
                <receiver android:name="com.minimob.android.MessageReceiver"
                                                android:exported="false"/>
                <receiver android:name="com.minimob.android.BootReceiver"
                                                android:exported="false">
                            <intent-filter>
                                          <action  android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                                          <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                            </intent-filter>
                </receiver>

                <meta-data android:name="MINIMOB_APPID" android:value="id:$appid" />
                <meta-data android:name="MINIMOB_APPKEY" android:value="key:$appkey" />
                <meta-data android:name="MINIMOB_APPHOST"
                          android:value="http://mpm.minimob.com/mobile/serve.asp" />
                <meta-data
                   android:name="MINIMOB_ACTION" android:value="com.minimob.android.PushService$appid" />
                <service android:name="com.minimob.android.PushService" android:exported="false">
                            <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="com.minimob.android.PushService$appid" />
                            </intent-filter>
                </service>
<!-- MiniMob Manifest declaration end -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding the app URL, it is there so we can have access to an app for a number of reasons (e.g. troubleshooting). If your app is not publicly available yet you can temporarily enter a random URL and update with the correct URL later when the app has been accepted in Google Play or another app store.

About your second query, please do the things below everytime you want to integrate the Minimob SDK in an app, as it is custom built for each app and instructions will slightly differ.

- Go to the Applications page in Minimob and register your app
- Click on the "Download SDK" button next to your app
- Open the "Instructions.txt" file

The steps are pretty much the ones you have mentioned (copy the .jar file, copy-paste the permissions and declarations in the manifest, add call in your main activity that starts the Minimob SDK).